# Goto mouse in Python turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I have been trying to make my turtle to forever go to my mouse after I press space (and draw behind), but every time it just crashes.  I know my programming is rubbish, but please help. Here is my programming:

```
    import turtle as t
    from turtle import *

    if input("Would you like to play the game (1), or draw shapes (2)? ") == "2":

        def k101():
            mousepen = 1
            screen = Screen()
            global screen
            while mousepen == 1:
                while screen.onscreenclick() == True:
                    screen.onscreenclick(t.goto)

        t.onkey(k101, " ") #mouse drawing
```

Comment: The indentation doesn't look right. Do you get a traceback?

Comment: `while screen.onscreenclick(t.goto) == True: screen.onscreenclick(t.goto)` I don't use turtle but that doesn't look right. Also, you declare `screen` global after `screen = Screen()` which is a warning.

Comment: yh sorry @roganjosh I did do global, and fixed the indentations, I did this question quickly so made these mistakes, also the ... == true was something that I had no clue about, so I just put that

Comment: and fixed the and @Fred Larson I have actually indented it correctly, I just did the question in a rush

Comment: Well a point of note: if you are expecting people to review things for you and put their own effort in to helping you, it's useful that you spend time putting your own effort into making the question as clear and specific as possible. The formatting can be fixed without any programming knowledge.

Comment: @roganjosh ok I will change the question a bit

Answer (score 0):

The following should do roughly what you want.  It won't do anything until you hit the space bar and then any time you click on the screen the turtle will head towards and goto the place you clicked:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
yertle = Turtle()

def k101():
    screen.onscreenclick(click_handler)

def click_handler(x, y):
    screen.onscreenclick(None)  # disable event inside event handler
    yertle.setheading(yertle.towards(x, y))
    yertle.goto(x, y)
    screen.onscreenclick(click_handler)  # reenable event on event handler exit

screen.onkey(k101, " ")  # space turns on mouse drawing

screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: This works, but I get a 'referenced before assignment' error when I run it

Comment: @Gurneyguy, I just copied it off the web page and it runs fine under Python 3 and works under Python 2 with adjustment to the final line (just use `mainloop()` and add it to the `import` list.) There are only two assignments and they occur first thing in the code, so I have to assume there's a copy error somewhere on your part and suggest you try again.

Comment: I have double-checked it, and neither of us have defined `click_handler` which is the cause of the error